# Converting strings Series to numeric one

Tags: pandas

I'm doing

```
X = data['x'].apply(lambda h: [int(h[i:i + 2], 16) for i in (0, 2 ,4)])
```

Where `x` has strings of hex colors, and I'd like to map them to RGB arrays (3 values each). After that, `X` has`dtype='object`, and `X.values` is a numpy array of numpy arrays.

My final goal is making it an `3 * n` numpy array and use it with `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`. What is the best way to achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

After creating X, you can split up the data into 3 columns like this

```
X = data['x'].apply(lambda h: [int(h[i:i + 2], 16) for i in (0, 2 ,4)])
data[['R','G','B']] = pd.DataFrame(X.values.tolist(), index=X.index)
```

so that

```
data[['R','G','B']]
```

has the result in three columns for further processing